# Assigning the model field values to a custom field in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have created a custom field in django admin using its admin class.Now I have a model field which is has corresponding database values in it.I want the custom field that i created using admin.py to have values of this model field .Is it possible to assign the model field values to a custom fields in django ?

Comment: ya, just override the `get_queryset` method.

Comment: I dont want to ovveride the whole model with some new filtered fields based on some query.I want a particular field "custom field" to have the values of model field ...If that can be done by get_queryset could you write some code for that ...It will be highly appreciated @AvinashRaj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Rather than declaring custom field in django admin class, you can create a method in Model class and populate corresponding value there.

Example code:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

    def _greetings(self):
        return 'Hello ' + self.name
    _greetings.admin_order_field = "name"

class ModelAAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["name", "_greetings"]
```

Comment: what is admin_order_field here ?@jbacker

Comment: It's used to sort the **_greetings** column in admin panel ui.